# Network configuration | apt can't download anything

Tags: networking, server, apt, firewall, ftp

I'm having some issues with the FTP server I'm currently setting up for my company. I installed the server completly, updated everything and the server works fine now. 
I installed everything behind a proxy in another network.
Now I moved the server to the place where it belongs, in its very own network without a proxy. The FTP ports are opened and the FTP is avaible from everywhere. 
But the problem I have now is, that exept for pings on direct IP-adresses and the ftp service, I can't install anything with apt-get or update anything.
Here are some configuration files for more information.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
        address 192.168.5.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.5.0
        broadcast 192.168.5.255
        gateway 192.168.5.254
```

`ifconfig`:

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:07:e9:80:42:ff
          inet addr:192.168.5.1  Bcast:192.168.5.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::207:e9ff:fe80:42ff/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2110 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2225 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:197740 (197.7 KB)  TX bytes:382977 (382.9 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:10072 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10072 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:814824 (814.8 KB)  TX bytes:814824 (814.8 KB)
```

The `apt.conf` is empty.

Things like `nslookup de.archive.ubuntu.com` and `ping google.com` don't work
The server is behind two firewalls and the guys from the company who maintain the firewall said that the ubuntu download server sources are allowed to connect.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have DNS working.

Add the directive to interfaces to enable it.

```
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

Full Example for your configuration.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
        address 192.168.5.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.5.254
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: You could also remove the network and broadcast declarations.

Comment: Great point, @chili555 , I removed them from my answer.  As further explanation, network and broadcast are calculated from address and netmask, so adding the directive is more likely to cause issues, if they are incorrectly added.

Answer (score 0):

you could also add.

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

to /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: It is not needed if it is included in `/etc/network/interfaces`. Also, it is actually `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: Depending on the system setup, this may be overwritten when the system restarts.